# Java Switch Statement, discount percent off

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am stuck trying to create a switch statement for my program. For full disclosure this is a homework assignment that is due tomorrow. I am supposed to use a switch statement to assign a discount rate for the total charge of CD's being sold. Gold being 15% off, Silver 10%, Bronze 5% and 0% for non members.

Here is my program so far. I have not gotten to the output yet, but that shouldn't be a problem as long as I cant get past this switch.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   //Variables
    String firstName = null;
    String lastName = null;
    int songs;
    double cost;
    int membership;
    double serviceCharge;
    double productCharge;
    double baseCharge;
   //Keyboard input
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   //Gathering information from the user
   System.out.println("Enter your first name:");
   firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter your last name:");
   lastName = keyboard.nextLine();       
   System.out.println("Enter the number of songs downloaded:");
   songs = keyboard.nextInt();
   System.out.println("enter the cost per song:");
   cost = keyboard.nextDouble();
   System.out.println("Enter the status of membership:"
           + "3 represents a gold member"
           + "2 represents a silver member"
           + "1 represeents a bronze member:"
           + "0 represents a nonmember");
   membership = keyboard.nextInt();

   //Here is where the math starts
   baseCharge = cost * songs;

   serviceCharge = baseCharge;
   if (songs <= 8)
       serviceCharge = .07 * baseCharge;
   else if (songs > 8 && songs <= 15)
       serviceCharge = .04 * baseCharge;
   else if (songs > 15 && songs < 20)
       serviceCharge = .02 * baseCharge;
   else if (songs <= 20)
       serviceCharge = 0;

   productCharge = baseCharge + serviceCharge;

   switch (membership)
   {
       case 3: productCharge * .15;              
           break; 
       case 2: 
           break;
       case 1: 
           break;
       case 0:
           break;
       default:
           break;
   }
```

Obviously you cannot use double in a switch statement, but I am lost. How am I supposed to assign the percent discount rate without using a double? you need decimals to do the math correctly. Or am I looking at this completely wrong?

Once I am done with the rest of the program this is what the output should look like.

Enter your first name:
John
Enter your last name:
Doe
Enter the number of songs downloaded:
8 
Enter the cost per song:
0.99 
Enter the status of membership:
3 represents gold member
2 represents silver member
1 represents bronze member;
0 represents nonmember:
1
Full Name: John Doe
Number of songs downloaded: 8
Price per song: $0.99
Service charge: $0.32
Subtotal: $7.60
Tax: $0.36
Total charge: $7.58

Sorry for the wall of text. Thank you very much in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the discount info in a `double` variable via `switch`/`case`:

```
   double discount = 0.0;//some default value

   switch (membership)
   {
       case 3: 
           discount = .15;              
           break; 
       case 2: 
           discount = .05
           break;
       //etc.
       default:
           discount = 0.0;//some default value
           break;
   }
   //now do the calculation using the discount variable
   double finalProductCharge = productCharge * (1.0 - discount);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helped with my project. Now I'm off to finish the rest!

Answer (score 0):

If the membership is 3 for gold, 2 for silver, 1 for bronze and 0 for none you can just calculate the percentage based on that without using a `switch`, since it's 5% per membership level.

```
final double discountPerMemberLevel = 0.05;

productCharge = baseCharge + serviceCharge;

double discount = membership * discountPerMemberLevel;
productCharge *= 1 - discount;
```

Comment: This works for the homework assingment in this example, but as a general coding practice I'd recommend the switch. If the user input or discount amounts ever changed, then the math doesn't work and its intent isn't very clear.

Comment: @StevenMastandrea well a better solution would be to store the percentages somewhere, like an array or database, and use them to calculate so the code stays clean. `switch` statements are quite messy really.

Comment: Great suggestion, I am sure that works wonderfully but I do not think that is what my professor is looking for. Mohammad hit the nail on the head. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

`productCharge * .15` is not a statement, which is what `switch` expects there, so the compiler gives you a message saying as much. A good next step would be to check the syntax for the switch statement. Anyway, evaluating that expression does not achieve anything yet.